# Granting SeServiceLogonRight to a user from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In a script I'm currently writing, I create a dedicated user for starting some windows services that we internally developed. In order to start those services, our "dedicated" user needs the SeServiceLogonRight privilege. Currently, I'm assigning that privilege using ntrights.exe with the following call from my PowerShell script:

```
{.$global:RootInstallDir\..\Common\SupportTools\ntrights.exe -m $env:COMPUTERNAME -u $HealthLinkUser +r SeServiceLogonRight }
```

However, I'm not satisfied with this. There must be a cleaner way of doing that with PowerShell.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313831/using-powershell-how-do-i-grant-log-on-as-service-to-an-account)

Comment: You'll need to p/invoke. This will get you started. http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1151

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me. You can decide which is cleaner ;-) The key is the LsaAddAccountRights windows API function.

```
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MyLsaWrapper
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Management;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    using LSA_HANDLE = IntPtr;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        internal int Length;
        internal IntPtr RootDirectory;
        internal IntPtr ObjectName;
        internal int Attributes;
        internal IntPtr SecurityDescriptor;
        internal IntPtr SecurityQualityOfService;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct LSA_UNICODE_STRING
    {
        internal ushort Length;
        internal ushort MaximumLength;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        internal string Buffer;
    }
    sealed class Win32Sec
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true),
        SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        internal static extern uint LsaOpenPolicy(
        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] SystemName,
        ref LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
        int AccessMask,
        out IntPtr PolicyHandle
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true),
        SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        internal static extern uint LsaAddAccountRights(
        LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle,
        IntPtr pSID,
        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] UserRights,
        int CountOfRights
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true),
        SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        internal static extern int LsaLookupNames2(
        LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle,
        uint Flags,
        uint Count,
        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] Names,
        ref IntPtr ReferencedDomains,
        ref IntPtr Sids
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32")]
        internal static extern int LsaNtStatusToWinError(int NTSTATUS);

        [DllImport("advapi32")]
        internal static extern int LsaClose(IntPtr PolicyHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32")]
        internal static extern int LsaFreeMemory(IntPtr Buffer);

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is used to grant "Log on as a service", "Log on as a batchjob", "Log on localy" etc.
    /// to a user.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class LsaWrapper : IDisposable
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LSA_TRUST_INFORMATION
        {
            internal LSA_UNICODE_STRING Name;
            internal IntPtr Sid;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2
        {
            internal SidNameUse Use;
            internal IntPtr Sid;
            internal int DomainIndex;
            uint Flags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LSA_REFERENCED_DOMAIN_LIST
        {
            internal uint Entries;
            internal LSA_TRUST_INFORMATION Domains;
        }

        enum SidNameUse : int
        {
            User = 1,
            Group = 2,
            Domain = 3,
            Alias = 4,
            KnownGroup = 5,
            DeletedAccount = 6,
            Invalid = 7,
            Unknown = 8,
            Computer = 9
        }

        enum Access : int
        {
            POLICY_READ = 0x20006,
            POLICY_ALL_ACCESS = 0x00F0FFF,
            POLICY_EXECUTE = 0X20801,
            POLICY_WRITE = 0X207F8
        }
        const uint STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED = 0xc0000022;
        const uint STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES = 0xc000009a;
        const uint STATUS_NO_MEMORY = 0xc0000017;

        IntPtr lsaHandle;

        public LsaWrapper()
            : this(null)
        { }
        // // local system if systemName is null
        public LsaWrapper(string systemName)
        {
            LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES lsaAttr;
            lsaAttr.RootDirectory = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.ObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.Attributes = 0;
            lsaAttr.SecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.SecurityQualityOfService = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES));
            lsaHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] system = null;
            if (systemName != null)
            {
                system = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
                system[0] = InitLsaString(systemName);
            }

            uint ret = Win32Sec.LsaOpenPolicy(system, ref lsaAttr,
            (int)Access.POLICY_ALL_ACCESS, out lsaHandle);
            if (ret == 0)
                return;
            if (ret == STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
            if ((ret == STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES) || (ret == STATUS_NO_MEMORY))
            {
                throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            }
            throw new Win32Exception(Win32Sec.LsaNtStatusToWinError((int)ret));
        }

        public void AddPrivileges(string account, string privilege)
        {
            IntPtr pSid = GetSIDInformation(account);
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] privileges = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
            privileges[0] = InitLsaString(privilege);
            uint ret = Win32Sec.LsaAddAccountRights(lsaHandle, pSid, privileges, 1);
            if (ret == 0)
                return;
            if (ret == STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
            if ((ret == STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES) || (ret == STATUS_NO_MEMORY))
            {
                throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            }
            throw new Win32Exception(Win32Sec.LsaNtStatusToWinError((int)ret));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (lsaHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32Sec.LsaClose(lsaHandle);
                lsaHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        ~LsaWrapper()
        {
            Dispose();
        }
        // helper functions

        IntPtr GetSIDInformation(string account)
        {
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] names = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
            LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2 lts;
            IntPtr tsids = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tdom = IntPtr.Zero;
            names[0] = InitLsaString(account);
            lts.Sid = IntPtr.Zero;
            Console.WriteLine("String account: {0}", names[0].Length);
            int ret = Win32Sec.LsaLookupNames2(lsaHandle, 0, 1, names, ref tdom, ref tsids);
            if (ret != 0)
                throw new Win32Exception(Win32Sec.LsaNtStatusToWinError(ret));
            lts = (LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tsids,
            typeof(LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2));
            Win32Sec.LsaFreeMemory(tsids);
            Win32Sec.LsaFreeMemory(tdom);
            return lts.Sid;
        }

        static LSA_UNICODE_STRING InitLsaString(string s)
        {
            // Unicode strings max. 32KB
            if (s.Length > 0x7ffe)
                throw new ArgumentException("String too long");
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING lus = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING();
            lus.Buffer = s;
            lus.Length = (ushort)(s.Length * sizeof(char));
            lus.MaximumLength = (ushort)(lus.Length + sizeof(char));
            return lus;
        }
    }
    public class LsaWrapperCaller
    {
        public static void AddPrivileges(string account, string privilege)
        {
            using (LsaWrapper lsaWrapper = new LsaWrapper())
            {
                lsaWrapper.AddPrivileges(account, privilege);
            }
        }
    }
}
'@

[MyLsaWrapper.LsaWrapperCaller]::AddPrivileges("andy", "SeServiceLogonRight")
```

Comment: I've used this as I don't want a dependency on ntrights.exe. It works but only on the second attempt. On the first attempt, it throws a Win32Exception in AddPrivileges - "The parameter is incorrect". Haven't worked out why yet.

Answer (score 19):

This script contains functions that work fine and without any dependencies:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Revoke-Query-user-26e259b0

Besides that, here is the concrete solution for your problem:

```
function Add-ServiceLogonRight([string] $Username) {
    Write-Host "Enable ServiceLogonRight for $Username"

    $tmp = New-TemporaryFile
    secedit /export /cfg "$tmp.inf" | Out-Null
    (gc -Encoding ascii "$tmp.inf") -replace '^SeServiceLogonRight .+', "`$0,$Username" | sc -Encoding ascii "$tmp.inf"
    secedit /import /cfg "$tmp.inf" /db "$tmp.sdb" | Out-Null
    secedit /configure /db "$tmp.sdb" /cfg "$tmp.inf" | Out-Null
    rm $tmp* -ea 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I had to remove "-Encoding ascii" from gc and sc to support non-ascii characters in usernames (e.g. äëöüï).

Comment: Thanks for the note. That is how it should be.

Comment: Coming back to this answer I was wondering: Isn't the /cfg parameter in the last secedit command redundant? We already import the template in the database through the /import command in the previous line.

Comment: @funforums It's not because import only imports the template into a database. Configure actually applies that database to the server.

Answer (score 7):

This really should be a comment to Andy's answer but I do not have the rep needed to comment.

The code as provided will access memory that has been freed -- which might "work" (sometimes) but is always bad practice. Please see my answer to another question about a problem with the same code: [Why might LsaAddAccountRights return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147914/why-might-lsaaddaccountrights-return-status-invalid-parameter/14469248#14469248)

It seems this code has been being passed around for several years.

Answer (score 3):

Basically the same P/Invoke technique to employ C# to call system DLL procedures, but this example may be a little easier to follow:

```
$code = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 public class TokenManipulator
 {

  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall,
  ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
  internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr
  phtok);

  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name,
  ref long pluid);

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  internal struct TokPriv1Luid
  {
   public int Count;
   public long Luid;
   public int Attr;
  }

  internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED = 0x00000000;
  internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
  internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
  internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;

  public static bool AddPrivilege(string privilege)
  {
   try
   {
    bool retVal;
    TokPriv1Luid tp;
    IntPtr hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
    IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
    retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
    tp.Count = 1;
    tp.Luid = 0;
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
    retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    return retVal;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    throw ex;
   }
  }

  public static bool RemovePrivilege(string privilege)
  {
   try
   {
    bool retVal;
    TokPriv1Luid tp;
    IntPtr hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
    IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
    retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
    tp.Count = 1;

    tp.Luid = 0;
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED;
    retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
    retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    return retVal;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    throw ex;
   }
  }

 }
"@

add-type $code

"`nInitial privileges"
whoami /priv | Select-String "SeRestorePrivilege"
whoami /priv | Select-String "SeBackupPrivilege"
whoami /priv | Select-String "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege"

"`nAdding privileges"
#Activate necessary admin privileges to make changes without NTFS perms
[void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege("SeRestorePrivilege") #Necessary to set Owner Permissions
[void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege("SeBackupPrivilege") #Necessary to bypass Traverse Checking
[void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege("SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege") #Necessary to override FilePermissions 
whoami /priv | Select-String "SeRestorePrivilege"
whoami /priv | Select-String "SeBackupPrivilege"
whoami /priv | Select-String "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege"

"`nRemoving privileges just added before terminating"
[void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege("SeRestorePrivilege") #Necessary to set Owner Permissions
[void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege("SeBackupPrivilege") #Necessary to bypass Traverse Checking
[void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege("SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege") #Necessary to override 
whoami /priv | Select-String "SeRestorePrivilege"
whoami /priv | Select-String "SeBackupPrivilege"
whoami /priv | Select-String "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege"
```

This confused me plenty, and there are plenty of examples of forum threads that ended in 'use a 3rd party' app. It would be nice if .Net included this necessary function, but despite the length of this code sample, it is pretty straightforward to reproduce :)
Cheers, Barnaby

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

Based on: [this article](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/11/Set-or-Grant-Logon-As-A-Service-right-to-User.html)

You can download [Carbon from here](http://get-carbon.org/)

First import Carbon module as follows:

```
Import-Module -Name $Path_To_Carbon -Global -Prefix CA

[array]$UserPrivileges = Get-CAPrivileges -Identity $UserName;
[bool]$LogOnAsAServiceprivilegeFound = $false;

if ($UserPrivileges.Length > 0)
{
    if ($UserPrivileges -contains "SeServiceLogonRight")
    {
        $LogOnAsAServiceprivilegeFound = $true;
    }
}

if ($LogOnAsAServiceprivilegeFound -eq $false)
{
    Grant-CAPrivilege -Identity $UserName "SeServiceLogonRight"
}
```